# Finding the PDF of Y, where Y = min X

Tags: self-study, density-function, order-statistics, extreme-value

Have $ X_{1},X_{2},\cdots,X_{10}$ random sample from a distribution with PDF:

$$ f(x;\theta) = e^{ - (x- \theta) },\,  \theta \leq x \lt \infty $$

Know that $ \hat{\theta}_{MLE} = Y = min(X_{i},\;i=1,2,\cdots,10) $

How do I go about finding the PDF of Y?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the general case. Assume $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots ,X_{n}$ are IID random variables with cumulative distribution function $F_{X}(x)$ and density $f_{X}(x)$.

The order statistics are:
$$X_{(1)}<X_{(2)}<\cdots<X_{(n)}$$

where

$$X_{(1)}=\text{min}(X_{1},X_{2},\ldots ,X_{n})$$

Let $Y=X_{(1)}$. The distribution function of the minimum can be derived as follows:

$$\begin{align}
F_{Y}(y)&=\text{Pr}(Y\leq y)\\
&=1-\text{Pr}(Y>y)\\
&=1-\text{Pr}(\text{min}(X_{1},X_{2},\ldots ,X_{n})>y)\\
&=1-\text{Pr}(X_{1}>y)\cdot\text{Pr}(X_{2}>y)\cdots\text{Pr}(X_{n}>y)\\
&=1-(1-F_{X}(y))^{n}
\end{align}$$

The density can be found by applying the chain rule to the distribution function:

$$f_{Y}(y)=n\cdot f_{X}(y)\cdot(1-F_{X}(y))^{n-1}$$

We know:

$$\begin{align}
F_{X}(y)&=\int_{\theta}^{y}e^{-(u-\theta)}du\\
&=\Big[-e^{-(u-\theta)}\Big]_{\theta}^{y}\\
&=1-e^{-(y-\theta)}
\end{align}$$

So,

$$f_{Y}(y)=10 e^{-10(y-\theta)}$$

Comment: Please review the wiki for the [tag:self-study] tag.

Comment: reviewed - your precise point is?

Comment: @MathR'tard I think his point was that I shouldn't have provided you with the complete answer, given this was deemed self study. Rather, you should be assisted in finding the answer yourself.

Comment: @StatsPlease OK to be fair I try to do the question and get as far as I can then ask for a hint rather than the full answer which is fair.

Comment: @MathR'tard If you're happy with the answer I provided, you can mark it as an accepted answer.